Do I have to downgrade my torchtext version? Vocab.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'specials'
My torchtext version is 0.17,using colab, and I get the message "Vocab.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'specials'". I found out that from torchtext version 0.10 these specials are accepted.
But it seems it's not working.
This is my code. I tried "vocab" instead of "Vocab". It didn't work for me.
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import spacy
import re
from torchtext.vocab import Vocab
import io
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm

nlp1 = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp2 = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")

#build vocab
def build_vocab(file, tokenizer):
 counter = Counter()
 with io.open(file) as f:
  for s in f:
   counter.update(tokenizer(s))
   return Vocab(counter, specials=['<unk>', '<pad>', '<bos>', '<eos>'])

en_vocab = build_vocab(source_path, nlp1)
        

